# openvpn tcp or udp (specific situation, reliability-layer collisions)

Tags: openvpn, tcp, udp

My question is whether to use TCP of UDP for my OpenVPN connection.
I've set up a simple network for a startup company that allows users from the outside to access the network via an OpenVPN server (in routing mode). The only thing users will do with the vpn is accessing files.

The priority is to keep the integrity of the files intact. With that in mind, should I use the UDP of TCP protocol for my vpn tunnel? I've read up on reliability-layer collisions (i.e. on http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html), but since tcp, the openvpn transport layer and the tunneled TCP session can all provide the reliability checks for me, so it leaves me wondering what would work best for me.

So, should I use TCP or UDP in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

UDP. Always UDP for tunneled connections if you can swing it from a network/firewall perspective. The underlying TCP flows will take care of retries if necessary. If you used TCP at the OpenVPN layer, you end up in a situation where both layers can send duplicate packets in the case of loss. This can cause significant performance problems.

Comment: one thing to add. always UDP unless we're setting up 'road warrior' scenario for users connecting from different networks/locations. for them VPN running on 443/tcp might be the last resort to access internal resources from some hotels, airports and other locations where the traffic is heavily filtered.

Comment: Good catch, @pQd. I would add that it's not hard to set up another "server" on the same physical host serving as a OpenVPN gateway which would listen 443/tcp. So the OP could first go with normal UDP setup and amend it with the TCP later, if needed.

Comment: you can also run multiple openvpn servers on the same machine/ip address, just different ports [and tcp / udp - depending on the necessity]

Comment: Actually UDP on port 53 is remarkably good for getting through firewalls if your openvpn service accepts it.  There's also a lot of wifi networks with open wifi, and a http based login system where you can bypass the security by tunelling through UDP port 53.